# CMUsphinx support for other languages

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

currently I am using Sphinx4 in a java desktop application to just to match some speech/words against the xxx.gram file. I have not installed sphinx in my system rather I'm just using sphinx4.jar in my project's classpath. And its working fine till now.

Now, I want to use it with Spanish, Portuguese, and Chinese languages. how could I do that? I don't want to install Sphinx. Is there any .jar file or light weighted code or services (even if other than sphinx) available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Spanish model here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Spanish%20Voxforge/voxforge-es-0.1.1.tar.gz/download

Portuguese and Chinese are not supported. If you need them you can build models from your audio, see for details

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

To make data collection easier you can use audiobooks.